# VueDatePcker, adding a custom button

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuepic-vue-datepicker

im using @vuepic/vue-datepicker": "^7.4.1" and I want to add a custom close button in the mobile view like this(I want to add the close button where the red square is).

[image]

I tried using action-row to add a button, but when I added auto-apply the action row disappeared. any idea how to do this? this is my current code

```
<template>
  <VueDatePicker
    v-model="dates"
    range
    :enable-time-picker="false"
    :multi-calendars="{ solo: true }"
    placeholder="Select date range"
    :max-date="new Date()"
    :auto-apply="true"
    :format="`dd MMM yyyy`"
    :preset-dates="presetDates"
    :end-year="new Date().getFullYear()"
    @internal-model-change="onchange"
  >
    <template #preset-date-range-button="{ label, value, presetDate }">
      <span
        role="button"
        :tabindex="0"
        @click="presetDate(value)"
        @keyup.enter.prevent="presetDate(value)"
        @keyup.space.prevent="presetDate(value)"
      >
        {{ label }}
      </span>
    </template>
  </VueDatePicker>

</template>
```